# Why didn't Devoe take Barry's power?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In Flash season 4 episode 18 ([**Lose Yourself**](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Lose_Yourself)) *Devoe* attack star labs and take the powers of all bus metas. He even takes away the power of *Killer Frost*. He could easily take the power away from *Barry* as he was laying on the floor or he could absorb his power too. Same in the case for *Cisco*.

So why didnt Devoe takes Flash's power?

Is it because Devoe can only absorb the powers of the bus metas?

Comment: Either bad writing or Devoe needs Barry for his masterplan. In any case, that will be answered in future episodes...

Comment: Obviously it’s a plot hole. If Barry’s out then Team Flash dies.

Comment: Plus, the season would end in just 18 episodes, so bad writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an answer in the finale episode: Devoe anticipated most of the events of this season so that Barry decided to enter Devoe's mind to fight him.

But, if Barry became trapped in Devoe's mind, the Thinker would have access to past, present and future knowledge through Barry's connection to Speed Force.

This, combined with the Enlightenment where people would have mentally regressed, would have made the Thinker a god.